# gRPC setup issue

Tags: vue.js, grpc

I am new at grpc and trying to setup an example with vue js. At the moment I am trying to follow this exmaple:
https://dev.to/thearavind/a-todo-app-using-grpc-web-and-vuejs-3p55

My issue is when I try to create the "stub file" for the server and client with the following:

```
protoc -I todo/ todo/todo.proto --go_out=plugins=grpc:todo
```

I get the following error:
*protoc : The term 'protoc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and tr
y again.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the *protoc* compiler and add it to your PATH. Downloads are available here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/